# Have to provide more specific type in class member function return type, but not argument type?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

recently a piece of code confused me:

```
class A {
 public:
  typedef int SomeType;

  void func(SomeType i);
  SomeType func2();
};

void A::func(SomeType i) {
  cout << "in A, value: " << i << endl;
}
SomeType A::func2() {
  return 123;
}

int main() {
  A a;
}
```

G++ 4.4 gives a compile error that it does not know the SomeType while compiling A::func2:

```
error: 'SomeType' does not name a type
```

But the same SomeType compiles well in **A::func(SomeType i)**:

```
class A {
 public:
  typedef int SomeType;

  void func(SomeType i);
};

void A::func(SomeType i) {
  cout << "in A, value: " << i << endl;
}
```

Anyone can help me to understand this? It seems C++ treats unfair to argument types and return types?

Comment: @Xeo: `typename`/`template` keywords are only needed for names dependent on template parameters. There's no templates here.

Comment: Using `A::SomeType` instead of `SomeType` outside of the class declaration fixes it.  http://ideone.com/1VZdy

Comment: @interjay: Right, nvm. Dealing so much with templates lately, that it just didn't occur that this is *not* one. :s

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think what confused me most is the first function compiles well but it also uses unqualified SomeType as parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc is right -

```
/* can't use unqualified name */  A:: /* can use unqualified name */  () {
}
```

Before the `A::`, you need to qualify the nested type with `A::`. So you need:

```
A::SomeType A::func2() {  
   //whatever
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I can understand this might be necessary, but what confused me is why the argument type does not need A::

Comment: @Kai it's just how the language works. After you qualify the definition with `A::func2`, you're already in the name scope of the class. Not that much to it. You shouldn't waste too much time on this. It's how the language is designed, pure and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
SomeType A::func2() {
```

to

```
A::SomeType A::func2() {
```

The reason that this differs from func1() is that `SomeType` is used in the parameter list there so that the compiler knows that it can look in `class A` for the type. However, with `func2()`, `SomeType` is the return type and the compiler doesn't know to look in `class A` yet.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the definition of func2 to:

```
A::SomeType A::func2() {
    return 123;
}
```

You need to tell the compiler you want to use the SomeType typename defined inside class A.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use this Qualify SomeType with the class name as in

```
  A::SomeType A::func2() {
      (...)
  }
```

SomeType cannot be used outside the A class and func2 is visible outside the A class
This URL - states the following in the C++ specification

http://balbir.blogspot.com/2005/06/scope-of-typedefs-in-class-in-c.html

In particular, type names defined within a class definition cannot be used 
outside their class without qualification.